# AWS Athena: Filter only numeric entries on a column

Tags: amazon-web-services, presto, amazon-athena

I am trying to make a query on AWS Athena, where I want to filter only numeric entries from a varchar column. However, Athena does not support ISNUMERIC function. I saw some functions that would be useful, but they are available only for Amazon Redshift and not for AWS Athena.
Is there any way to apply this type of filter on Athena? Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this with [`try()`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/conditional.html#try):

```
... 
WHERE try(CAST(my_column AS double)) IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You can also use `try_cast`: `WHERE try_cast("my_column" AS double) IS NOT NULL`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`regexp_like`](https://prestosql.io/docs/0.172/functions/regexp.html#regexp_like):

```
…
WHERE regexp_like(my_column, '^-?\d+$')
```

This would match positive and negative integers, if you want to match decimals you need a more complex pattern, of course.